$a_k$ strictly increasing to $+\infty$, can we say $\sum e^{-a_kx}$ converges for $x>0$?

$a_k$ strictly increasing to $+\infty$, can we say $\sum e^{-a_kx}$ converges for $x>0$?

If $a_k$ has an order, say $a_k> k^s$, then $1/e^{a_kx}<\frac{1}{1+(k^sx)^m/m!}$. So for $m$ large, $sm>1$, then it is OK by comparison test...But here $a_k$ is just strictly increasing

With $b_k = e^{-a_k x}$ an equivalent formulation of your conjecture would be: If $(b_k)$ is strictly decreasing to zero then $\sum b_k$ is convergent. Can you see now that this is wrong?

No. For example $a_k=\log k$ and $x=1$

Intuitively, we can have the impression that have exponential of minus something that growths to infinity can help, but if the growth is too slow, this will not be helpful.
Take $a_k=\log\log k$ for $k\geqslant 3$ so that for each $x$, $e^{-a_k x}=\left(\log k\right)^{-x}$ hence $\sum_{k=3}^\infty e^{-a_k x}$ diverges for each $x>0$.

A naive approach can be as follows. Fix a sequence $b_k\searrow 0$ such that $b_k<1$ and  $\sum b_k=\infty.$ For a fixed $x>0$ let $a_k$ satisfy $b_k=e^{-a_kx},$ i.e. $a_k=-x/\log b_k.$ Then $a_k$ is positive, increasing  and $$ \sum e^{-a_kx}=\sum b_k=\infty$$
